# the action can't be completed because the file is open in openjdk platform binary spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, image, file, delete-file

Hey I'm trying to delete a image (file) but I can't :(

That how I upload the image:

```
 try {
            List<String> imagesPaths = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String image : imagesBytes)
            {
                String base64Image = image.split(",")[1];
                byte[] imageByte = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64Image);
                String folder = "C:/images/" + LoggedInUser.UserId();
                File newDirectory = new File(folder);
                if (!newDirectory.exists())
                {
                    newDirectory.mkdirs();
                }
                long timeMilli = new Date().getTime();
                String imageType = image.substring("data:image/".length(), image.indexOf(";base64"));
                String path = timeMilli + "." + imageType;
                Files.write(Paths.get(folder, path), imageByte);
                String newPath = LoggedInUser.UserId() + "/" + path;
                imagesPaths.add(newPath);
            }
            logger.debug("uploadImages() in ImageService Ended by  " + LoggedInUser.UserName());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(imagesPaths, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ApiRequestException(e.getMessage());
        }
```

And this how I delete it :

```
    List<ImageJpa> images = imageRepository.findByStatus(Image.UNUSED.status);
    System.out.println(images.size() + ": Images are not used");
    images.forEach(image -> {
        String imagePath = "C:/images/" + image.getPath();
        System.out.println(imagePath);
        File imagePathFile = new File(imagePath);
            if (imagePathFile.exists())
            {
                boolean isDeleted = imagePathFile.delete();
                if (isDeleted)
                {
                    imageRepository.deleteById(image.getId());
                    System.out.println("Deleted the file: " + imagePathFile.getName());

                } else {System.out.println("Failed to delete the file. :" + imagePathFile.getName());}
            }else {
                System.out.println("Already Deleted");
            }
    });
```

Always I got (Failed to delete the file ...)

- Note : The image will deleted if I ReRender the the project again or close and open the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on other function :\

I was open the files after save it without **CLOSE the connection** after it !

This one what was messing on the read files

```
inputStream.close();
```